# Java segmentation fault at libglib (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5)

Tags: linux, jboss, segmentation-fault, java

has anyone ever seen the following Java segmentation fault at libglib g_list_last? The stack shows nothing more than the g_list_last and it says that "Current thread is native thread".
The Java 6 VM was running JBOSS 6 and there was no custom native code.

The server runs normally for some hours and then breaks... always with the exactly same error. I'm posting the most interesting excerpts from the hs_err file.

Thanks in advance for any clue!

Regards,
Doug

---

```
    #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000003e5022a5e3, pid=14845, tid=1196464448
    #
    # JRE version: 6.0_23-b05
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (19.0-b09 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  [libglib-2.0.so.0+0x2a5e3]  g_list_last+0x13
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
    #

    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread is native thread

    siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000010068f06abb

    Registers:
    RAX=0x0000010068f06ab3, RBX=0x000000004d59ee10, RCX=0x000000004e60aeb0, RDX=0x0000000000000000
    RSP=0x0000000047508e18, RBP=0x00002aaab9afcca0, RSI=0x00002aaab9afcca0, RDI=0x0000010068f06ab3
    R8 =0x0000000000000001, R9 =0x0000000000003a93, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000003e5022abb0
    R12=0x000000047c6556b8, R13=0x00002aaab8c7a3f0, R14=0x000000004d698e40, R15=0x000000004da3c4b0
    RIP=0x0000003e5022a5e3, EFL=0x0000000000010202, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
      TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e
```

...

```
    R11=0x0000003e5022abb0
    0x0000003e5022abb0: g_list_append+0 in /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 at 0x0000003e50200000

    R12=0x000000047c6556b8

    [error occurred during error reporting (printing registers, top of stack, instructions near pc), id 0xb]

    Stack: [0x00000000474c9000,0x000000004750a000],  sp=0x0000000047508e18,  free space=255k
    Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    C  [libglib-2.0.so.0+0x2a5e3]  g_list_last+0x13


    ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

    VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

    VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

    Heap
     PSYoungGen      total 4767296K, used 4345622K [0x00000006c2800000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
      eden space 4368704K, 99% used [0x00000006c2800000,0x00000007caaac208,0x00000007cd250000)
      from space 398592K, 4% used [0x00000007cd250000,0x00000007ce369990,0x00000007e5790000)
      to   space 373184K, 0% used [0x00000007e9390000,0x00000007e9390000,0x0000000800000000)
     PSOldGen        total 10403840K, used 1828930K [0x0000000447800000, 0x00000006c2800000, 0x00000006c2800000)
      object space 10403840K, 17% used [0x0000000447800000,0x00000004b7210910,0x00000006c2800000)
     PSPermGen       total 288448K, used 288427K [0x0000000347800000, 0x00000003591b0000, 0x0000000447800000)
      object space 288448K, 99% used [0x0000000347800000,0x00000003591aaf10,0x00000003591b0000)
```

...

```
    ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

    OS:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)

    uname:Linux 2.6.18-194.el5 #1 SMP Tue Mar 16 21:52:39 EDT 2010 x86_64
    libc:glibc 2.5 NPTL 2.5 
    rlimit: STACK 10240k, CORE 0k, NPROC 1056767, NOFILE 16384, AS infinity
    load average:1.01 0.58 0.40

    /proc/meminfo:
    MemTotal:     132086452 kB
    MemFree:      12656648 kB
    Buffers:       1441372 kB
    Cached:       107627992 kB
    SwapCached:          0 kB
    Active:       77778444 kB
    Inactive:     39851400 kB
    HighTotal:           0 kB
    HighFree:            0 kB
    LowTotal:     132086452 kB
    LowFree:      12656648 kB
    SwapTotal:    61440552 kB
    SwapFree:     61440552 kB
    Dirty:             864 kB
    Writeback:           0 kB
    AnonPages:     8560164 kB
    Mapped:          84312 kB
    Slab:          1645472 kB
    PageTables:      31956 kB
    NFS_Unstable:        0 kB
    Bounce:              0 kB
    CommitLimit:  127483776 kB
    Committed_AS: 20373196 kB
    VmallocTotal: 34359738367 kB
    VmallocUsed:    297932 kB
    VmallocChunk: 34359436991 kB
    HugePages_Total:     0
    HugePages_Free:      0
    HugePages_Rsvd:      0
    Hugepagesize:     2048 kB


    CPU:total 32 (8 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 47 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht

    Memory: 4k page, physical 132086452k(12656648k free), swap 61440552k(61440552k free)

    vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (19.0-b09) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_23-b05), built on Nov 12 2010 14:12:21 by "java_re" with gcc 3.2.2 (SuSE Linux)
```